# Determining the big Oh for (n-1)+(n-1)

Tags: math, big-o

I have been trying to get my head around this perticular complexity computation but everything i read about this type of complexity says to me that it is of type big O(2^n) but if i add a counter to the code and check how many times it iterates per given n it seems to follow the curve of 4^n instead. Maybe i just misunderstood as i placed an count++; inside the scope.

Is this not of type big O(2^n)?

```
   public int test(int n) 
   {    
   if (n == 0)
   return 0;
   else
   return test(n-1) + test(n-1);
    }
```

I would appreciate any hints or explanation on this! I completely new to this complexity calculation and this one has thrown me off the track.

//Regards

Comment: Try counting it up (by hand) for the first few `n`s (say `0<=n<=5`) and I think it'll make sense fairly quickly. However, as it's written now it'll return `0` no matter what `n` you begin with.

Comment: What was the code with the counter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int test(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);

    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return test(n - 1) + test(n - 1);
    }
}
```

With a printout at the top of the function, running `test(8)` and counting the number of times each `n` is printed yields this output, which clearly shows 2<sup>*n*</sup> growth.

```
$ ./test | sort | uniq -c
    256 0
    128 1
     64 2
     32 3
     16 4
      8 5
      4 6
      2 7
      1 8
```

(`uniq -c` counts the number of times each line occurs. `0` is printed 256 times, `1` 128 times, etc.)

Perhaps you mean you got a result of O(2<sup>*n*+1</sup>), rather than O(4<sup>*n*</sup>)? If you add up all of these numbers you'll get 511, which for *n*=8 is 2<sup>*n*+1</sup>-1.

If that's what you meant, then that's fine. O(2<sup>*n*+1</sup>) = O(2⋅2<sup>*n*</sup>) = O(2<sup>*n*</sup>)

Answer (score 1):

Let x(n) be a number of total calls of `test`.

```
x(0) = 1

x(n) = 2 * x(n - 1) = 2 * 2 * x(n-2) = 2 * 2 * ... * 2
```

There is total of n twos - hence 2^n calls.

Answer (score 1):

First off: the 'else' statement is obsolete since the if already returns if it evaluates to true.

On topic: every iteration forks 2 different iterations, which fork 2 iterations themselves, etc. etc. As such, for n=1 the function is called 2 times, plus the originating call. For n=2 it is called 4+1 times, then 8+1, then 16+1 etc. The complexity is therefore clearly 2^n, since the constant is cancelled out by the exponential.

I suspect your counter wasn't properly reset between calls.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity `T(n)` of this function can be easily shown to equal `c + 2*T(n-1)`. The recurrence given by

```
T(0) = 0
T(n) = c + 2*T(n-1)
```

Has as its solution c*(2^n - 1), or something like that. It's O(2^n).

Now, if you take the input size of your function to be `m = lg n`, as might be acceptable in this scenario (the number of bits to represent `n`, the true input size) then this is, in fact, an `O(m^4)` algorithm... since O(n^2) = O(m^4).